# Image to appear on text input

Tags: jquery

So I am currently building a sort of "live preview", and need a placeholder image to appear when information is entered into an `<input>` tag. I currently am using this as my live preview code for the text fields on the page, but cannot get it to work for the image.

```
$(function() 
{
    $(".companyname").keyup(function() 
    {
        var companyname=$(this).val();
        $(".cn_preview").html(companyname);
        return false;
    });

    $(".tagline").keyup(function() 
    {
        var tagline=$(this).val();
        $(".tag_preview").html(tagline);
        return false;
    });
$(".map").keyup(function() 
        {
            var map=$(this).val();
            $(".map_preview").html(map);
            return false;
        });

    $(".about").keyup(function() 
    {
        var about=$(this).val();
        $(".abt_preview").html(about);
        return false;
    });
```

The placeholder image will be positioned relatively over another image. The structure for that is as such:

```
    <div id="displaycontain">
                <div id="previewbottom">
                    <h2 class="previewbottom">Preview Changes</h2>
                <img src="images/previewimage.png" border="0" style="margin-left: auto; width: 100%;" />
                </div>
                <div class="action" id="publishbutton">
                    <input type="button" value="PUBLISH" class="myButton"></div>
                <div id="test">
                    <h4 name="cnpreview" class="cn_preview">Company Name</h4>
                    <p name="tagprev" class="tag_preview">Tagline here.</p>
                    <p name="aboutprev" class="abt_preview">This is where your description goes.</p>
<img src="images/googlemap.png" name="mapplace" class="map_preview" border="0" />

                </div>
            </div>
```

And the css for that:

```
.cn_preview {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    position: relative;
    top: -298px;
    left: 78px;
    width: 200px;
}
.tag_preview {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    position: relative;
    top: -288px;
    left: 78px;
    width: 100px;
}
.abt_preview {
     color: #000000;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    position: relative;
    top: -258px;
    left: 78px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

This may be a long shot, but any sort of help or direction on where to go would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want a placeholder image to appear? What have you tried? What is not working? What would you want to have in the placeholder?

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: Edited original, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean adding the same image before the previewed text, first change your code to use one single function: (to avoid redundant code)

```
$(function() 
{
    $(".companyname").keyup(function() 
    {
        return  Preview($(this), "cn_preview");
    });

    $(".tagline").keyup(function() 
    {
        return  Preview($(this), "tag_preview");        
    });

    $(".about").keyup(function() 
    {
        return  Preview($(this), "abt_preview");        
    });
});
```

Then add the image in the function:

```
function Preview(oTextbox, sPreviewClass) {
    var previewImageSrc = "preview.png";
    var value = oTextbox.val();
    var oPreviewPanel = $("." + sPreviewClass);
    oPreviewPanel.empty();
    if (value.length > 0) {
        oPreviewPanel.append($("<img />").attr("src", previewImageSrc));
        oPreviewPanel.append(value);
    }
    return false;   
}
```

The above will also hide the preview panel when there is no text.

<strike>jsFiddle is now down, will add live test case when it will be back.</strike>

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/9sUXQ/1/).

**Edit**: from your comments on my original answer, looks like the above is not necessary in your case. First, just have the image hidden by default:

```
<img src="images/googlemap.png" name="mapplace" class="map_preview" border="0" style="display: none;" />
```

Then instead of assigning its HTML in this line: (which is meaningless)

```
$(".map_preview").html(map);
```

Have such line to show the image:

```
$(".map_preview").show();
```

When you want it hidden again (e.g. in the other preview functions) have:

```
$(".map_preview").hide();
```

Comment: Thats really close, but is there a way to do it without the text appearing?

Comment: @nick what do you mean "without the text appearing"? What text? Isn't it the whole purpose of preview?

Comment: Maybe I wasnt too clear, for which I apologize, jQuery is still very new to me. Basically, the text would appear, sans image, for tagline, companyname, and about, and the image would appear, sans text, for the map_preview.

Comment: @nick sorry still can't understand. What is "sans image"?

Comment: @nick what you described above is the problem, or the desired behavior?